# Head first Android 2 для новичка?

Tags: java, android, книги, мобильная-разработка

знаю java на среднем уровне, недавно начал изучать андроид по книге head first Android 2. Как она для новичка в целом? Что посоветуете? И какие книги/ресурсы читать далее?

Comment: Я читал html css у headfirst  — хорошая вещь. Наверно джава тоже неплохая...

Answer (score 0):

Смотрел этот видос: [Войти в IT через Minecraft и Яндекс / Всё о Kotlin и Android / Интервью с Kotlin Developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9zlTFLLrSI)
и удивился, что паренёк советует startandroid.ru - т.к. некоторые уроки *11 года. Также и другие источники сообщали, что startandroid.ru норм сайт для начала.
+один из источников высказал своё мнение, что в ру сегменте хорошие видео курсы на эту тему, а вот книги Г.
*(все источники действующие разрабы)*

PS Это не моё мнение, а то что почерпнул лопатя сеть по подобному вопросу.

Comment: Ну я сам учился по startAndroid. И да там реально первые уроки 11-ого года. Но почти все то что было в 11 году актуально и сейчас. К тому же парнишка не положил болт на свой сайт, а регулярно добавляет новый контент. Сейчас к примеру он активно пушит туда уроки по Kotlin. Так что ресурс очень актуален